# Is it possible to use hundreds of Android devices with the same google account?

Tags: google-account, google-play-services

We have developed a App that uses GCM push, that seems that needs Google Play Services (Google account).

Customer has 100-200 devices, it it possible to use the same google account in all devices? Gmail will be inactivated, and buy apps to Market will be disallowed.

Aditional info: We have proposed Google for Work, but Customer is not interested at this moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a quick google search, seems like there is no limit placed devices connected to your Google account. The only apparent restriction is four devices for [Google Music](http://www.droid-life.com/2014/08/08/yep-google-re-introduced-their-4-device-limit-on-deauthorizations-in-google-music/).

Aside from a [bug](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/OeOmhUPWqTo), there no documented device restrictions.